# Prepared DB Query from _POST array

Tags: php, ajax, mysql

hey guys i'm somewhat a beginner in wordpress, and wrote my own theme now

> Question: what is the proper way of doing a sql query to a custom mysql table in combination with POST Data.

The problem is, that the data are getting double escaped, and i've no idea how to avoid this:

## The following scenario:

an input comes via ajax

The input value: **example'with'quotes**

Worpress autoescapes in wp-settings.php the post array using `wp_magic_quotes()`

After that the input looks like: **example\'with\'quotes**

If i try to print out the last query via `$this->wpdb->last_query` in my Products_Model it shows something like

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE name = 'example\\\'with\\\'quotes'
```

which shouldn't be happen ;)

### My Code - what i've tried so far

functions.php (excerpt)

```
require_once(__DIR__."/inc/core/AppWpActions.php");
```

AppWpActions.php (excerpt)

```
class AppWpActions
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addSiteActions();
    }

    private function addSiteActions()
    {
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_web_products', [$this, "showProducts"]);
        add_action('wp_ajax_web_products', [$this, "showProducts"]);
    }

    public function showProducts()
    {
        require_once(get_template_directory()."/inc/modules/products/controllers/Product.php");
        $objProduct = new Product();
        $objProduct->setAjaxList();

    }
]
```

Product Class

```
class Product
{
    public function setAjaxList()
    {
        require_once(get_template_directory()."/inc/modules/onlineshop/models/Product_Model.php");
        $objProduct = new Product_Model();
        $arrData = $objProduct->getProducts($_POST['search']);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($arrData);
        wp_die();
    }
}
```

Product Model

```
class Product_Model
{
    private $wpdb;
    private $arrStatusMessages = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    }

    public function getProducts($strSearch = "")
    {
        if (!empty($strSearch))
        {
            $arrData = $this->wpdb->get_results($this->wpdb->prepare("
                SELECT *
                FROM product
                WHERE
                    name = %s
            ", $strSearch));

            return $arrData;
        }
        else
        {
            return [];
        }

    }
}
```

thx in advance for your answers

Comment: How do you insert `example'with'quotes`, which method is used for saving/validating/escaping etc?

Comment: this is a search request so no need for saving; according to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/ - it sanitizes the arguments and returns a Sanitized query string